# Translate CSV to ANSI ASC X-12 Standards

Tags: csv, edi, x12

My boss just asked me to convert many CSV files to ANSI X12 Standards text files. I have no idea how to do this. Wonder if there is an app or software to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the CSV a standard format or a custom one? If the answer is a custom CSV, then I would say no, you would need to code it yourself (maybe with integration software such as BizTalk).  Do you want the EDI or XML ASC X-12. Which particular ASC X-12 format do you want to translate it to?

Comment: Check my profile I can point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a plethora of software packages that can help you translate CSV to EDI.  What EDI documents do you need to create?

[Liaison Delta](http://liaison.com/products/transform/delta) and ECS can do it quite easily (and my recommendation).  CSV is a very common file format.  There are a ton of universal data translators that have this functionality.  Boomi, Sterling Commerce, GXS/Inovis, Extol, 1EDISource.  There are also hosted solutions like SPS Commerce and DI Central that will do the translation for you.